# Why doesn't find list files in subdirectories?

Tags: find

I'm trying to find all the javascript files in subdirectories of my project.

The working tree is as follows:

```
.
├── app
├── assets
├── components
├── email.txt
├── gulpfile.js
├── node_modules
└── package.json
```

For that end I say:

```
find . -name *.js
```

or

```
find . -path *.js
```

Strangely, first command reports only `gulpfile.js`, while the second one reports nothing. But I have `.js` files in `app`, `components` and `node_modules`! Why wouldn't they show up?

Comment: Use single quotes on the file name, as `find . -name '*.js'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put single quotes around `*.js`. Without quotes, the shell is expanding the wildcard to filenames that match in the current directory, so `find` only gets those filenames, either in the current directory or sub-directories in the find spec (but never sees the wildcard). To specify it as a pattern for `find` to use, you need to prevent the shell expansion. `'*.js'` does that.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to forget that shell globbing still plays a role in the process. Thus you need a way to tell shell to avoid expanding `*` to a list of files. One way is via what Chris Johnson mentioned - quoting.

Another is via escaping the `*` character, as in

```
find . -iname \*.js
```

Compare:

```
$ strace -e trace=execve find -maxdept 1 -iname *.js > /dev/null                                      
execve("/usr/bin/find", ["find", "-maxdept", "1", "-iname", "file1.js", "file2.js"], [/* 75 vars */]) = 0
find: unknown predicate `-maxdept'
+++ exited with 1 +++

$ strace -e trace=execve find -maxdept 1 -iname \*.js > /dev/null                                     
execve("/usr/bin/find", ["find", "-maxdept", "1", "-iname", "*.js"], [/* 75 vars */]) = 0
find: unknown predicate `-maxdept'
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

In first case we see that `*` was expanded to list of files `file1.js` and `file2.js` that are present in the current working directory. In second example - the `*` is treated as literal argument to `find`. In fact, this is the same result produced by quoting the argument:

```
$ strace -e trace=execve find -maxdept 1 -iname '*.js' > /dev/null                                    
execve("/usr/bin/find", ["find", "-maxdept", "1", "-iname", "*.js"], [/* 75 vars */]) = 0
find: unknown predicate `-maxdept'
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Alternatively , you could use the octal value of `*` instead.

```
$ strace -e trace=execve find -maxdept 1 -iname $'\52'.js > /dev/null                                 
execve("/usr/bin/find", ["find", "-maxdept", "1", "-iname", "*.js"], [/* 75 vars */]) = 0
find: unknown predicate `-maxdept'
+++ exited with 1 +++
```